# Receiving onTaskRemoved() callback two time in Android Service

Tags: android, kotlin, service

I have created a START_NOT_STICKY Service while the app is running in foreground/background. When I kill the application from the recent list for the first time I am getting the callback only once and from onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) callback, I am calling stopSelf().

After that when I am relaunching the app the Service is restarted but again when remove/kill the application from the recent apps I am receiving the onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) twice. Could anybody help me understand how this is possible?

```
2019-06-25 12:38:49.840 E/BluetoothService: onTaskRemoved
2019-06-25 12:38:49.845 E/BluetoothService: onTaskRemoved
2019-06-25 12:38:49.852 I/BluetoothService: Service onDestroy
```